# TFS Team Foundation Server 2010 - Structure - projects in multiple solutions - what the Best practice?

Tags: tfs

we've recently started using TFS2010 for source control.

It's working well with the first solution we have migrated.

```
$/TeamProject
    /Main
        /Source (contains solution)
            /Project1
                /Source
            /Project2
                /Source
            /ProjectN
                /Source
    /Releases

        /x.x.x  
            (similar structure)
```

The question I have is what is the best way for set up projects that are referenced by multiple solutions?

Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: should i use branching across solutions for the projects that are shared? or is there a way of linking them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much wrong with this approach. There are some good breakdowns in the [Patterns and Practices](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%203%20-%20Structuring%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20in%20Source%20Control&referringTitle=Home) book on Code Plex. I'd also recommend [TFS 2010 by Wrox](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.productCd-0470943327.html) as some essential reading on the subject.

I'll point out a caveat the book doesn't though. If you are branching one project inside another.

E.g.

```
$/TeamProject
  /Main
    /3rd Party DLLs (<-Branched from $/3rd Party/Bin)
    /Source
$/3rd Party
  /Main
    /bin
    /Sources
```

Then you cannot create a branch from Main in $/TeamProject.

Comment: which is going to be a problem.  the idea behind creating a main and releases branches was to provide isolation for sp/fix etc whilst we continue dev.  If by creating a branch of another project in the main team project would prevent this I need to find another way.   Maybe I should add a folder for compiled references and treat the compiled assemblies as version controlled files in the project? then would have to update manually?

Comment: That's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

One way I often recommend is to have the same structure you showed above, but have all solution files in the same folder (Main/Source) with all of the projects in subfolders below.  This way you could pick any projects that the solution requires and the projects can belong to more than one solution.  This will prevent any source code structure warnings that could display if your projects are not under the solution structure.

Some care has to be given when you build the solutions.  The solutions should usually be built at the same time so dependant DLLs are the same version.

Mike

Comment: Thanks for input mike.  the more i delve into this it seems there is no elegant solution.  It's a shame you can't link vs projects across team projects

Comment: I know, that would be helpful sometimes.  You can branch across team projects, so you could essentially have copies of your projects across the team projects.  This may be a good option if you are actively making changes to shared libraries where the applicaitons using the libraries can be released at different times requiring different versions.

Comment: thanks Mike, I think that's what the initial response from Dave was driving at, but you then cannot branch a project which contains a branch of a project from another team project?

Answer (score 0):

I have to -1 for the book reference. It is missing something that is extremely basic. The ability to add existing solutions into a branch (/Main) that they reference in that book. Everywhere else on the net (literally, everywhere, even Microsoft) recommend you not to do that ...

If that is a bad practice then who knows what else isn't good in that book.